# How Can I read a file at preprocessing time

Tags: c++, c, file, cmake, file-handling

I need to compile my code based on version number of the project i am working on.
In short, i will read the version number from a file and enable or disable certain part of my code/.
How can i read the version number from a file at compile time in c/c++?.

I am trying to do something like this

```
static const unsigned int version =   
#include "version"
    ;
```

I am getting compiler error.

Comment: Have your build system supply the macros...

Comment: And what is the exact problem with the given code? If you are getting an error you should post build log here.

Comment: I assume this should work, although everybody in his right mind would just have a `config.h` and `#define VERSION 42.11` there, or have the build system pass a `-DVERSION=42.11`.

Comment: @StoryTeller : I tried adding a macro in my CmakeLists.txt file.
But the macro is not working in my header file.It works in cpp file

Comment: @VTT : Error: Expected an expression

Comment: And the content of the file `version` is ...?

Comment: @kashifahmad Can you show us what you did in the `CmakeLists.txt` and the header file, and which error messages exactly you got please?

Comment: @Angew : content of the file is a number like 1300065

Comment: @user0042 

file (STRINGS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../GDK/Common/include/version" BUILD_NUMBER)  
math(EXPR GDKVERSIONMAJOR "${BUILD_NUMBER} / 1000000 % 100")
MESSAGE( STATUS "GDKVERSIONMAJOR: " ${GDKVERSIONMAJOR} )
if(GDKVERSIONMAJOR STREQUAL "13")
add_definitions(-DGDK13_SUPPORT=1)
endif(GDKVERSIONMAJOR STREQUAL "13")

Comment: You should add build log into your question, not into comment.

Comment: @kashifahmad [edit] your question please to add additional information. Code is hardly readable in comments.

Comment: *I am getting compiler error.* -- tell us what the error is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

## file.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
static const float version = 
#include "file.h"
;

int main()
{
 printf("Version is : %f\n", version);
}
```

## file.h

```
37.11
```

basically works

Comment: Can I do something like below??                                                                                                       

static const unsigned int version =
#include "version" / 1000000) % 100
; 

#if (version == 14)                                                  
#define GDK14_SUPPORTED 1                                         
#elif(version == 13)                                                        
#define GDK14_SUPPORTED 0                                                  
#endif

Comment: why won't you try it yourself?

Comment: @EladHazan you just copy pasted OP's code and said it works.