# Is there a way to assign a value to a macro by reading a value from another file?

Tags: c++, c

I am working on C++ project. I have a file named *"version"* where only *12343* like number is defined [In fact the version] in numeric form. 
This *"version"* file is defined in Library A. 
Somehow I need to assign this value to a macro in another library B file.

Is there any way to do it?

Since, the work is official, so I can't share the code here.

Comment: What form does "library A" take?  If it's a compiled blob, extracting anything useful from it at compile-time is going to be fairly tricky.  You may be better off at a preprocessing/code-generation step as part of your build system.

Comment: So your file named "version" is a text file containing just one line, for example `12343`? Please [edit]  your question and make that clear _there_

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of: [How Can I read a file at preprocessing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259465/how-can-i-read-a-file-at-preprocessing-time#comment81470150_47259465) asked today (by potentially the same user)

Comment: @VTT it's not quite the same, here he wants to put the content of a one line file into a `#define` (at least that's what I understood) and in the question you mention he wants to assign a value to a global variable.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Yes the file name is "version" and it contains a version number like you mentioned. Now I just need to assign this value to a macro during pre-processing. This would enable me to use some compiler guards based on the value of the macro.

Comment: @user3505805 please make that clear _in your question_. You can [edit] it. BTW your comment is truncated.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do this (not quite sure though), but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259465/how-can-i-read-a-file-at-preprocessi) is similar and the answer works.

Comment: @VTT: It seems very similar to the post you mentioned, but here I need to assign a value to a macro, that too, at pre-processing. This will help me use some compiler guards.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Thanks. Even I consider the same. So, just wanted to confirm from you guys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158868/discussion-between-user3505805-and-michael-walz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ has a language feature that would allow you to set the expansion text of a macro to something read at compile time from an external file.  Such tasks are generally assigned to the build system, instead.

There are diverse mechanisms for the purpose, but they follow this general procedure:

- An external program reads the file containing the wanted text
- That program either

  - formats the text of a compilation option conveying the definition (e.g. `-DVERSION=${what_I_read_from_the_file}`), or
  - writes a header file containing the macro definition itself, e.g.

    ```
    #define VERSION version-text-from-the-file
    ```
- Either way, the obtained information is provided to the build in the appropriate manner -- the compiler option alternative proceeds by ensuring that the chosen option is passed to the compiler at build time, whereas the header alternative depends on the files that need the macro `#include`ing the generated header.

Comment: For the former, there's no need for a (new) external program -- you can just use `-DVERSION=$(cat version)` on your command line, letting the shell do the expansion for you...